# Mailing labels for Avery 5160

Tags: letters

I recently switched my Xmas mailing labels from MS Word to LaTeX using the following, and was wondering if anyone knew a better solution.  I will admit that [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17340/a-package-to-make-stickers/17344?r=SearchResults&s=12%7C13.9448#17344) is a more general solution, but I still have a nearly full box of Avery 5160 labels.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}% Avery 5160
\usepackage[top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, left=0.125in, right=0.125in, noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newenvironment{cell}{\minipage[c][1in][c]{2.75in}\centering% Avery 5160 described as 1in by 2.625in
  \varwidth{2.625in}\raggedright}% but measures 2.75in wide
{\endvarwidth\endminipage\allowbreak\ignorespaces}
  
\parindent=0pt
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\large% set font etc.
\begin{cell}
Name\\
Address\\
City, State Zip\\
extra line if needed
\end{cell}
\begin{cell}
Name\\
Address\\
Very wide city name, State Zip
\end{cell}
\begin{cell}
Name\\
Address\\
City, State Zip
\end{cell}
\begin{cell}
Name\\
Address\\
City, State Zip
\end{cell}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `texdoc elguide` is the manual for `envlab`

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I setup and do mine, which will need adapting to a multi-label-width page, since mine are Avery 4013, "3.5" x 15/16" One Across".  It is basically a strip of 12 labels on a single column.  My `\setlabel` tunes the vertical extent of the content to fit the label space.  If you think it is too big, add a blank line.  In the preamble, I highlight some of the parameters that can be tweaked if I change label format.

Format can be adjusted to multi-label-width format by specifying a wider paper, removing blank lines between `\setlabel` entries on the same row, and by removing the `\par` from the definition of `\setlabel`.  SEE BELOW 1ST SOLUTION.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4.3275in,paperheight=12in,left=0.4in,right=0.4in,
  top=.63in,bottom=.12in]{geometry}% top= tuned to your printer
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\parindent 0in
\parskip .24in% Related to label width
\usepackage{Palatino}% Pick a font with good stroke width
\newlength\htone
\newlength\httwo
\htone=.73in% related to label height
\httwo=.73in% related to label height

\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\strutlongstacks{T}

\def\setlabel#1{\hfil%
  \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{0in}{\htone}\scaleto{\Longstack{#1}}{\httwo}%
  \par%
}
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}

\setlabel{
Pastor Theophilus Jones\\
St. Luke Lutheran Church}% Wife Betsy

\setlabel{
Dr. \& Mrs. Greg Lastname \& Family\\
908 Streetname Dr.\\
Lancaster, PA 17601}% Liz + Kenny and Susie

\setlabel{
Herr Doktor Johann Schmidt\\
Birkenstrasse 27\\
86240 Biburg\\
GERMANY}% Mom's Uncle
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**MULTI-WIDTH**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10in,paperheight=12in,left=0.4in,right=0.4in,
  top=.63in,bottom=.12in]{geometry}% top= tuned to your printer
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\parindent 0in
\parskip .24in% Related to label width
\usepackage{Palatino}% Pick a font with good stroke width
\newlength\htone
\newlength\httwo
\htone=.73in% related to label height
\httwo=.73in% related to label height

\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\strutlongstacks{T}

\def\setlabel#1{\hfil%
  \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{0in}{\htone}\scaleto{\Longstack{#1}}{\httwo}%
%  \par%
}
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}

\setlabel{
Pastor Theophilus Jones\\
St. Luke Lutheran Church}% Wife Betsy
\setlabel{
Dr. \& Mrs. Greg Lastname \& Family\\
908 Streetname Dr.\\
Lancaster, PA 17601}% Liz + Kenny and Susie

\setlabel{
Herr Doktor Johann Schmidt\\
Birkenstrasse 27\\
86240 Biburg\\
GERMANY}% Mom's Uncle
\setlabel{
Frau Doktor Johanna Schmidt\\
Birkenstrasse 27\\
86240 Biburg\\
GERMANY}% Mom's Uncle
\end{document}
```

[image]